# Множественное наследование для методов

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть класс `Bot` и два публично наследованных от него класса `EasyBot` и `HardBot`. В родительском классе есть метод, который в классах наследуемых я переопределяю:

```
class Bot
{
private:
    CellStatus botColor;
public:
    Bot()
    {
        int guga = getRandom();
        switch (guga)
        {
            case(1):
            {
                this->botColor = CellStatus::White;
                break;
            }
            case(2):
            {
                this->botColor = CellStatus::Black;
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                this->botColor = CellStatus::Empty;
                break;
            }
        }

    };
    ~Bot(){};

    virtual int getStatus() const {
        return botColor;
    }

    virtual Cell getBotMove(vector <Cell> possibleBotMoves) const { return possibleBotMoves.front(); };

};


class EasyBot : public Bot
{
public:
    EasyBot() :Bot() {}

    Cell getBotMove(vector <Cell> possibleBotMoves) //Получает случайную позицию из получаемого вектора ячеек и возвращает как возможный ход
    {
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, possibleBotMoves.size());
        int randomPosition = dist(gen);

        return (possibleBotMoves.at(randomPosition));
    }
};

class HardBot : public Bot
{
public:
    HardBot() :Bot() {}

    Cell& getBotMove() {};
};
```

В зависимости от ввода пользователя я передаю экземпляр одного из наследуемых классов в функцию `Game`:

```
switch (difficultyChoice)
{
    case(1):
    {
        Bot* bot2 = new HardBot();
        Field startingField = Field(*bot2);
        Game(*bot2, startingField);
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        Bot* bot1 = new EasyBot();
        Field startingField = Field(*bot1);
        Game(*bot1, startingField);
        break;
    }
}
```

Функция принимает аргументы следующим образом:

```
static void Game(const Bot& bot, Field mainField)
```

В чём проблема:
Когда я пытаюсь вызвать внутри функции Game метод `bot.getBotMove()`, вызывается он из родительского класса, хотя сам объект `bot` может являться, например экземпляром класса `EasyBot`:
[image: Объект bot на этапе компиляции программы]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли это исправить не вводя проверки на тип класса и используя методы с одинаковым названием?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в родителе `virtual Cell getBotMove(vector <Cell>) const`, а в наследниках `Cell getBotMove(vector <Cell>)` и `Cell& getBotMove()`. Это разные методы. Приведите их к одному виду.

C `c++11` в методах класса наследника можно использовать спецификатор `override`, чтобы удостовериться, что вы переопределяете виртуальную функцию.

```
class EasyBot : public Bot
{
public:
    EasyBot() :Bot() {}

    Cell getBotMove(vector <Cell> possibleBotMoves) override //Ошибка. Метод ничего не переопределяет
    {
        //...
    }
    
    Cell getBotMove(vector <Cell> possibleBotMoves) const override //Переопределение родительского метода
    {
        //...
    }
};
```

А ещё вам стоит использовать виртуальный деструктор `virtual ~Bot() {}`.